# Making changes to flask app without db.drop_all(), db.create_all()

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, git-merge, flask-migrate

I have a flask app that is deployed on Google's App Engine. I have noticed a minor bug and I would like to fix it but my database is already populated.

How can I make this minor code change and push / deploy back to my app without losing all my data? (which is probably a basic question but I'm not finding much. all tutorials online are focused on creating the app and deploy, not updating)

Thus far, I have been dropping and re-creating the tables whenever I redeploy, mostly out of ignorance. Here are the steps I have followed

1. 1). make the change in my app
2. commit and push changes to bitbucket source code
3. in Google Cloud SDK: git pull
4. Google Cloud SDK: gcloud app deploy

These steps result in an empty database because the directory I am pushing from my local computer has an empty database. Is this where I should be using git merge?

Is this a database "migration" or is this a "git merge"? I'm not sure what the right terms are to use to research this further. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of angles to your question. I'm going to try to give you some information, but let me warn you, this isn't going to be a trivial change to your workflow, you'll have to change some things.

First of all, based on the way you worded your question I get the idea that you commit your database to git along with your code. If I got this right, then this is something that you need to stop doing. The database is not code, so it should not be committed to source control.

You should have a completely independent database on each installation of your application. For example, you will have a database on your own machine to do development. You will also need another database in your gcloud deployment. You may need more databases if you have other uses for your application. A very common third database for many people is one that is used for automated tests, which could also be located in your local development machine, but is not the same database that you use for day to day development.

To make changes to your database schema you will not drop and recreate tables anymore, that is clearly something that you already realized that needs an improvement. A good approach to make these changes is to use a database migration framework. These tools allow you to generate short scripts that make these changes to the database in a more focused way, without destroying and recreating everything, and for that reason, the data is in general not lost. For Flask-SQLAlchemy, the best option for database migrations is Flask-Migrate, which is a lightweight wrapper around the Alembic migration framework. (I might be biased here as I'm the author of the Flask-Migrate extension!).

Documentation for Flask-Migrate: https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Thanks, Miguel. I actually installed and setup Flask-Migrate by following your great tutorial that can be found here for other users: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database So, when you say that I "should have a completely independent database on each installation of your application" I suppose this means I should probably have a cloud database using Google's RDS product?

Comment: Yes. Either a database specific offering from Google, or a self-hosted database in a cloud instance. Both options are valid.